# Query not fully showing

Tags: php, mysql, edit

The Query I want to get from my database is not fully showing. 
Its about the *$straat* query. All the other queries are perfectly fine.

Problem described :

**This is the normal result on the main page**

At Straat & Huisnummer its showing "Roelofs Mulderweg 3"

[image: This is the normal result on the main page]

**This is the problem when I try to edit it with the script**

As you can see at Straat & Huisnummer the query is not fully showing anymore.

[image: This is the problem when I try to edit it with the script]
**THE PHP**

```
//selecting data associated with this particular id
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tt WHERE id=$id");

while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $track = $res['track'];
    $straat = $res['straat'];
    $postcode = $res['postcode'];
    $plaats = $res['plaats'];
    $land = $res['land'];
    $datum = $res['datum'];
    $klantnummer = $res['klantnummer'];
}
?>
```

**The HTML**

```
        <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
            <td>Track & Trace</td>
            <td>Straat & Huisnummer</td>
            <td>Postcode</td>
            <td>Plaats</td>
            <td>Land</td>
            <td>Datum</td>
            <td>Klantnummer</td>
</tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:100%" name="track" value=<?php echo $track;?>></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:100%" name="straat" value=<?php echo $straat;?>></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:100%" name="postcode" value=<?php echo $postcode;?>></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:100%" name="plaats" value=<?php echo $plaats;?>></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:100%" name="land" value=<?php echo $land;?>></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:100%" name="datum" value=<?php echo $datum;?>></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:100%" name="klantnummer" value=<?php echo $klantnummer;?>></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
                <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">

</form>
```

Comment: Where are your form tags in your `HTML`?

Comment: Try to check generated html

Comment: Take a look at the HTML source. It seems that the blank in the street field is what is causing you troubles (if that is true, in the source code the complete record should be there). If so, replace `value=<?php echo $straat;?>` with  ' value="<?php echo $straat;?>" ` (notice the hyphens)

Comment: Thanks again Burki !

Comment: @burki can we chat ?

Comment: sure, create a channel please

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87163/php-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment:

```
value=<?php echo $straat;?>>
```

breaks due to the whitespace in the value. Replacing this line with

```
value="<?php echo $straat;?>">
```

(note the hyphens) solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
        <td>Track & Trace</td>
        <td>Straat & Huisnummer</td>
        <td>Postcode</td>
        <td>Plaats</td>
        <td>Land</td>
        <td>Datum</td>
        <td>Klantnummer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" style="width:100%" name="track" value="<?php echo html_special_chars($track);?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" style="width:100%" name="straat" value="<?php echo html_special_chars($straat);?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" style="width:100%" name="postcode" value="<?php echo html_special_chars($postcode);?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" style="width:100%" name="plaats" value="<?php echo html_special_chars($plaats);?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" style="width:100%" name="land" value="<?php echo html_special_chars($land);?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" style="width:100%" name="datum" value="<?php echo html_special_chars($datum);?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" style="width:100%" name="klantnummer" value="<?php echo html_special_chars($klantnummer);?>"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo html_special_chars($_GET['id']);?>">                
<input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
```

You had 7 `td`'s in one `tr` and 8 in anoter

also:

1) dont forget to place your attribute values in quotes

2) use html_special_chars on output values, to prevent xss and breaking markup

Comment: While your catch is correct, it does not solve the problem.

Comment: One more hint: the hidden field at the end of the table might be counter-productive. It is quite possible that the application returns several result sets, all of which might require the hidden field. Adding that to one of the "normal" `<td>` appears to be a better solution, imho.

Comment: that id is not an array. so there will be the last value. also it has certain  value $_GET['id']

Comment: That is true... I would still personally prefer my approach (funny, isn't it? :-) ) but yes, yours is definitely valid.